# What does $(n|p)=1$ mean?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, notation

My number theory book mentions the following condition:

> $(n|p)=1$, where $p$ is prime.

What does $(n|p)=1$ mean? I used to think $n|p$ implies that $n$ divides $p$.

Comment: Without context, it is hard to say; could it be the [Legendre Symbol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_symbol) ?

Comment: Normally Legendre symbol is typeset as $\left(\dfrac n p\right)$, but that fits better than anything to do with divisibility. Note: $n\mid p$ has a true/false value, but the Legendre symbol has $\pm1$ as its value.

Comment: As a moderator I am curious about the following. There are 18 accounts named "algebraically_speaking" all using the same IP address. Care to explain?

Comment: What is the book? What is the context of the quotation?

Answer (score 3):

This is the [Legendre symbol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_symbol):

> **Definition.** Let $ p $ be a prime number and $ n \in \Bbb{Z} $. Then
>   $$
> (n|p) \stackrel{\text{df}}{=}
> \begin{cases}
> 1  & \text{if $ n \equiv x^{2} ~ (\text{mod} ~ p) $ has a solution and
>            $ n \not\equiv 0 ~ (\text{mod} ~ p) $}, \\
> -1 & \text{if $ n \equiv x^{2} ~ (\text{mod} ~ p) $ has no solution}, \\
> 0  & \text{if $ n \equiv 0 ~ (\text{mod} ~ p) $}.
> \end{cases}
> $$

As Jyrki has mentioned in his comment above, this is usually typeset as $ \left( \dfrac{n}{p} \right) $ instead.